# Getting empty recordset for a particular column during code run

Tags: asp-classic

I am using an Inline SQL statement Select * from table where column='' in classic asp application. This is a dynamic sql. Based on the return values in the recordset I am displaying some fields like checkboxes and text boxes. But this is working only if I put a breakpoint in specific / anywhere in the code file. while the code is running without any breakpoints actual results is not coming out.

Comment: Provide a code example, on a side note you should look at sanatizing your query parameters to avoid SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use:

```
your_record_set_name.moveNext
```

Otherwise you won't be able to fetch any records.

Comment: Hi Safraz, Thanks for the reply.

I am getting all the columns to the recordset but the problem is when the code is running without any breakpoints it is not behaving as that of with breakpoints. When the site is running with out breakpoints one particular value is pulled as empty in the recordset which is actually not empty.!!

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of the Response.Buffer ?

Try setting this at the top of your asp page.

```
<%  Response.Buffer = True  %>
```

And you do have

```
<%  Option Explicit %>
```

at the top of your page, no ?  Just to make sure you made no typo's somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Edelcom:  Read this document on how to use Markdown in SO answers:-
http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help